# Deserialize TOML string to enum using config-rs

Tags: rust, serde, toml

I'm using config-rs to load the configuration from a TOML file and I want to deserialize a string to an enum. I tried to solve it using the `deserialize_with` feature of serde_derive but I don't know how to return a suitable Error to satisfy the function signature. How can I achieve it?

My dependencies:

```
config = "0.7"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde = "1.0"
toml = "0.4"
```

Example code where it's intended to deserialize the enum `RotationPolicyType`:

```
extern crate config;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate toml;

use std::env;
use config::{Config, Environment, File};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use serde;
use serde::de::Deserializer;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub enum RotationPolicyType {
    ByDuration,
    ByDay,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct FileConfig {
    pub rotations: i32,
    #[serde(deserialize_with="deserialize_with")]
    pub rotation_policy_type: RotationPolicyType,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Settings {
    pub threads: usize,
    pub file_writer: FileConfig,
}

impl Settings {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut s = Config::new();
        s.merge(File::with_name("config/default")).unwrap();
        s.merge(File::with_name("config/local").required(false))
            .unwrap();
        s.merge(Environment::with_prefix("app")).unwrap();
        s.deserialize().unwrap()
    }
}


fn deserialize_with<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<RotationPolicyType, D::Error> where D: Deserializer {
    let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    match s.as_ref() {
        "ByDuration" => Ok(RotationPolicyType::ByDuration),
        "ByDay" => Ok(RotationPolicyType::ByDay),
        _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("error trying to deserialize rotation policy config"))
    }
}



fn deserialize_with2<'de, D>(deserializer: &'de mut D) -> Result<RotationPolicyType, D::Error> where &'de mut D: Deserializer<'de> {
    let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    match s.as_ref() {
        "ByDuration" => Ok(RotationPolicyType::ByDuration),
        "ByDay" => Ok(RotationPolicyType::ByDay),
        _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("error trying to deserialize rotation policy config"))
    }
}
```

Compilation error with *deserialize_with*:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/settings.rs:30:94
   |
30 |     fn deserialize_with<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<RotationPolicyType, D::Error> where D: Deserializer {
   |                                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Compilation error with *deserialize_with2*:

```
error[E0220]: associated type `Error` not found for `D`
  --> src/settings.rs:42:90
   |
42 |     fn deserialize_with2<'de, D>(deserializer: &'de mut D) -> Result<RotationPolicyType, D::Error> where &'de mut D: Deserializer<'de> {
   |                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^ associated type `Error` not found

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: *but I did not succeed* — why did you not show how you didn't succeed? Does the code not compile? Does the code not work as expected? What happened? What TOML file did you try to decode?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me a minute to update the question with my attempt.

Comment: Serde itself has [some examples of what is expected here](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde/src/de/mod.rs#L262). Specifically it looks like you want to use `Error::custom(....)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your example does not compile far enough to get to the errors you are describing. Please take care to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time. Bonus points for getting it to work on https://play.rust-lang.org (which is possible, the `extern crate config` is entirely unnecessary in your example).

After fixing up all the compilation issues, your first error is simply fixed by  changing the function API to match the one suggested [in the serde docs](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serdedeserializewith--path)

```
-fn deserialize_with<     D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<RotationPolicyType, D::Error> where D: Deserializer
+fn deserialize_with<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<RotationPolicyType, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de>
```

The error tried to help you there. It told you that `Deserializer` is missing a lifetime parameter.

The second function is telling you that `D` has no associated type `Error`. Which it can only have if `D` would implement `Deserializer<'de>`. But you specified that `&'de mut D` implements `Deserializer<'de>`. Finding the solution to this problem is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: the crate *config* is necessary to use config::Config as show in Settings::new(). It's not possible to reproduce in play-rust since it doesn't have crate config, but the code doesn't need any change to reproduce the error. What issues did you have to fix?

Comment: @oli_obk_ker I really appreciate your advice. I got lost playing with the lifetime and passing the deserializer by reference and in the end the solution was quite simple. Also IDEA had played tricks on me about the visibility of `serde :: de :: Error :: custom`. Anyway, thank you for your time! I'll post the solution to share it with anyone who has the same problem.

Comment: Reproduction in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ca29c20db012f5688204a62631b5d218&version=stable The `new` method is not necessary for your repro ;)

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of @oli-obk-ker the solution was quite simple:

```
use std::env;
use config::{Config, File, Environment};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use serde;
use serde::de::Deserializer;
use serde::Deserialize;

pub trait DeserializeWith: Sized {
    fn deserialize_with<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer<'de>;
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub enum RotationPolicyType {
    ByDuration,
    ByDay
}

impl DeserializeWith for RotationPolicyType {
    fn deserialize_with<'de, D>(de: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> where D: Deserializer<'de> {
        let s = String::deserialize(de)?;

        match s.as_ref() {
            "ByDuration" => Ok(RotationPolicyType::ByDuration),
            "ByDay" => Ok(RotationPolicyType::ByDay),
            _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("error trying to deserialize rotation policy config"))
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct FileConfig {
    pub rotations: i32,
    #[serde(deserialize_with="RotationPolicyType::deserialize_with")]
    pub rotation_policy_type: RotationPolicyType,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
pub struct Settings {
    pub threads: i32,
    pub file_writer: FileConfig,
}

impl Settings {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut s = Config::new();
        s.merge(File::with_name("config/default")).unwrap();
        s.merge(File::with_name("config/local").required(false)).unwrap();
        s.merge(Environment::with_prefix("app")).unwrap();
        s.deserialize().unwrap()
    }
}
```